# Environment.tickcount in java

Tags: java, jsp

What is the equivalent for this C# code in Java?

```
int tick = 0;
tick = Environment.TickCount;
```

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve with this? `Environment.TickCount` is rarely a *useful* property anyway - I don't know of a direct equivalent, but if we knew what you were trying to use it for, we'd have a better chance of helping you.

Comment: I need to Get the number of milliseconds elapsed since the system started.whats the apt code for java

Comment: @Saranya JON knows Environment.TickCount gives Get the number of milliseconds elapsed since the system started.He is asking **what you were trying to use it for??**

Comment: @Saranya: Exactly as vikiiii says - my point is that that's very rarely a useful piece of information, especially in a web application. Why do you think it's really useful? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Am getting UUID for a session. In that i need to add this tick count and by adding this i ll send this id and tick count for hashing algorithm.

Comment: For those still coming across this one, ticks are a very important construct when writing code. Time values can go forward and backward, depending on how the end user sets their clock, or how the time service on the system sets the time. Hence, you cannot guarantee that every time value retrieved will come after the next. System ticks, on the other hand, always increase, and can be used for things like checking on locks, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There's no standard way to get the system up time in Java. If you know that you're on a Unix-like system, you can use:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec('uptime');
```

Or you can read the system file:

```
new Scanner(new FileInputStream("/proc/uptime")).next();
```

On some systems, this will also be the value returned by `System.nanoTime()`, but there's no guarantee about the origin for `System.nanoTime()` (or even that the return value will be positive).

If the only reason you want this is to measure elapsed time, you can use `System.nanoTime()` or, if you want to measure elapsed wall clock time (including any adjustments that might have been made while doing the timing), use `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Answer (score 0):

As @TedHopp mentions, one possibility is to use System.currentTimeMillis(). In my case I wanted a "tick count" in seconds, not milliseconds. Here's what I'm currently using for the Java version of a corresponding C# method.

```
   // Static field used by the tickCountInSeconds() method
   private static long _firstCallTimeSeconds = 0;
```

...

```
   /**
    * Method to get an arbitrary constantly increasing time in seconds, i.e., a time in seconds that
    * can be used to compare the relative times of two events, but without having any other meaning.
    *
    * The .Net version of this method uses the Windows "tick count" facility, but since that doesn't
    * exist in Java we fake it by getting the system (Unix-style) time in milliseconds and
    * converting it to seconds. But to avoid the "year 2038 problem" (or to avoid criticism for
    * creating a year 2038 vulnerability) the time of the first call is saved in a static field and
    * subtracted from the returned result.
    */
   private synchronized static int tickCountInSeconds() {
      long currentTimeSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
      if (_firstCallTimeSeconds == 0) {
         _firstCallTimeSeconds = currentTimeSeconds;
      }

      return (int)(currentTimeSeconds - _firstCallTimeSeconds);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/** A different way to get this information in Tomcat JSP is as such: */
<%@ page import="java.lang.System.*" %>
<body>
<%
long uptime = ((System.nanoTime()) / 1000000);
int days = (int) Math.floor(uptime / 86400000);
int  hours = (int) Math.floor((uptime % 86400000) / 3600000);
int  minutes = (int) Math.floor((uptime % 3600000) / 60000);
int  seconds = (int) Math.floor((uptime % 60000) / 1000);
int  decpart = (int) (uptime % 1);
String struptime = "Days: " + days + ", HMS: " + hours + ":" + minutes + 
":" + seconds;
%>
</body>
/**
The Variable - struptime - can be directly used in a Paragraph, Table or 
the line can be modified to any use.

Andrew Bindner
*/
```